# Unable to view traps through snmptrad?

Tags: snmp, centos

I've been unable to view traps through `snmptrapd`. I generated a SNMP trap manually using the below provided `snmptrap` command:

```
snmptrap -c public -v 2c -n "" localhost 0 uptime
```

But I'm unable to capture the trap using the below provided `snmptrapd` command:

```
snmptrapd -f -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs -m inUnixPlatformApp-MIB -Os
```

**Question:** How can I capture the `snmptrap` in `snmptrapd`?

#### Installed software

I have the following RPM packages installed on the RHEL 6.3 server:

```
# rpm -qa|grep -i snmp
net-snmp-libs-5.5-41.el6.x86_64,
net-snmp-libs-5.5-41.el6.i686,
net-snmp-devel-5.5-41.el6.x86_64,
net-snmp-5.5-41.el6.x86_64,
net-snmp-perl-5.5-41.el6.x86_64,
net-snmp-utils-5.5-41.el6.x86_64,
perl-SNMP_Session-1.12-4.el6.noarch
```

#### System info

- Linux Rhel:  6.3
- SNMP Master Agent version: 5.5
- SNMP Protocol version: v2C

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you try the `snmptrapd` command?

Comment: Where's the output?

Comment: No, i do not have any error messages while i run snmp trapd command..please find the start & end of the dump snmptrapd here:- # snmptrapd -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs -m  inUnixPlatformApp-MIB  -f -n -Ddump
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
registered debug token dump, 1
NET-SNMP version 5.5
dumpx_recv:02 01 01
.......
2014-01-25 22:33:55 UDP: [127.0.0.1]:40313->[127.0.0.1] [UDP: [127.0.0.1]:40313->[127.0.0.1]]:
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.1.3.0 = Timeticks: (0) 0:00:00.00     SNMPv2-SMI::snmpModules.1.1.4.1.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.1.3

Comment: In continuation to my previous comment, in dump mode of snmptrapd i am able to see the lines of trap but that seems to be in improper format or not the actual trap, because the snmptrapd when run in normal mode(without dump) i do not get any traps, it just goes blank after the following 3lines:            [root@eirsnmp ~]# snmptrapd -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs -m airwide-solutions-inUnixPlatformApp-MIB  -f -n -Ddump
No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
registered debug token dump, 1
NET-SNMP version 5.5
The trapd terminal will now be blank forever even after generating snmptraps !!

Comment: You don't specify the `-L` option to `snmptrapd`, so the output destination (standard output, standard error output, syslog, or a specified file) is determined by the `snmptrapd.conf` configuration file. If the configuration file does not exist or does not specify the output destination, then the compile-time defaults are used - and they might not be what you expect. If you want output to the terminal you used to run `snmptrapd`, add a `-Lo` option to the `snmptrapd` command line to be explicit about it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by turning up the debugging output from `snmptrapd`. You can do so like this:

```
$ snmptrapd -D all -f -M /usr/share/snmp/mibs -m inUnixPlatformApp-MIB -Os
```

You can see the full list of "all" the valid tokens you can provide for debugging if you want to target things more explicitly here, [Debug tokens 5.4.2.1](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Debug_tokens_5.4.2.1).

Comment: Hi, i tried the -D mode of snmptrapd and found an error in the last line stating: getaddrinfo("all", NULL, ...): Temporary failure in name resolution
couldn't open all -- errno 3 ("No such process")                                                        Is this a reason for my trap not being captrued on snmptrapd?   If yes, how to overcome the err, because i see i am able to ping the server through hostname but still getting the above err !! Please help..

Comment: @user57619 - I would try changing it to the IP addr. to see if that's the real issue or a false positive.

Comment: Hi, I do not have an option to change the IP, as is my office server and i should stick on to the same ip..  But the issue does not seem to be with IP or hostname because i am able to ping the servers from other servers through both hostname and IP..

Comment: @user57619 - I wasn't suggesting to change your IPs, but to use the IP instead of the hostname. The resolving of a hostname to an IP can happen in a variety of ways on Linux, so this was meant to eliminate this as a possible issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry i misunderstood, could you please let me know where exactly you want me to swap the Hostname to that of IP please..

Comment: @user57619 - use the `-n` switch.

Comment: I did the following: snmptrap -c public -v 2c -n "" 10.3.7.68 0 uptime, but still i am unable to capture any traps in snmptrapd output :(

Answer (score 0):

SNMP traps arrive as UDP packets to port 162. Is your `iptables` configured to allow incoming SNMP traps?